# Creating an ID to aggregate similar records using information obtained from multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm doing an analysis of scientific publications from around 30,000 journals. My list has over 1.3 million records but with several duplicates (ex: a paper with more than one author from different institutions appear more than once).

Well, I would like to perform a record comparison that would result in a new ID column with the same value for the same papers. This would be very easy with dplyr if the records were equal, but there are several matching problems, as different authors may include the information in distinct ways, or they can make mistakes.

Here is an example of the type of records and problems I have, and the type of ID I would like to generate:

```
ID  YEAR    DOI                         ISSN        Title                                                                                           Vol BegPg   EndPg   Authors 
001 2018    10.1093/brain               0006-8950   JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis    141 1609    1621    ALVES   
001 2018    10.1093/brain/awy105        0006-8950   JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis    141 1609    NA      ALVES | CALVET | TOQUET | AMELIN | DEPP | RODERO | HATHAZI | DUFFY | LANDON-CARDINAL    
001 2018    10.1093/brain/awy105        0006-8950   JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis    141 1609    NA      ALVES | CALVET | TOQUET | LANDON-CARDINAL | AMELIN | DEPP | RODERO | HATHAZI | DUFFY    
001 2018    10.1093/brain/awy105        0006-8950   JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis    141 1609    NA      BENJAMIM    
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     /A  NA              LUCATO | FREUA | CABRAL 
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     XX  NA              GIANNETTI | PAIVA | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO | THOMSEN | BASU | FREUA | LYNCH  
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     X           NA      PAIVA | LUCATO | FREUA | GURGEL-GIANNETTI | LYNCH | YAMAMOTO | THOMSEN | BASU | GIANNETTI   
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     1   NA      NA      YAMAMOTO | JULIANA GURGEL-GIANNETTI | DAVID S LYNCH | ANDERSON RODRIGUES BRANDÃO DE PAIVA | LEANDRO TAVARES LUCATO | CHRISTER THOMSEN | SOMSUVRO BASU | FERNANDO FREUA  
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     13  3096    NA      GIANNETTI   
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     13  AWY172  NA      GIANNETTI | LYNCH DS | PAIVA ARB | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO G | THOMSEN C | BRASU S | FREUA F  
002 2018    10.1093/brain/awy172        0006-8950   A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2                     141 2289    2298    GIANNETTI | PAIVA | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO | FREUA | LYNCH | THOMSEN | BASU  
003 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121       0007-2745   The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Brazilian Atlantic Forest        121 480     497     MENEZES | CACERES | BASTOS | LÜCKING    
003 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121       0007-2745   The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Brazilian Atlantic Forest.       121 480     497     MENEZES | CACERES | LÜCKING | BASTOS    
003 2018    NA                          0007-2745   The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Br. Atlantic Forest              121 480     497     MENEZES | CACERES | BASTOS | LÜCKING    
004 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121       0007-2745   Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes: Forest in southern Brazil  21  547     553     SANTOS | OLIVEIRA   
004 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547 0007-2745   Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes                             121 547     553     OLIVEIRA | PERALTA | SANTOS 
004 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547 0007-2745   Floristic composition, and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes                            121 547     553     SANTOS | OLIVEIRA | PERALTA 
004 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547 0007-2745   Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes                             121 547     553     SANTOS | PERALTA | DE OLIVEIRA  
005 2018    10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.571 0007-2745   Bryophytes of Jau National Park (Amazonas, Brazil): Estimating species detectability            121 571     588     PINILLA | GRADSTEIN | M.R. PEREIRA | BASTOS | ZARTMAN | VANDERPOORTEN   
005 2018    NA                          0007-2745   Bryophytes of Jau National Park (Amazonas, Brazil)                                              121 571     588     PINILLA | VANDERPOORTEN | GRADSTEIN | BASTOS | ZARTMAN | PEREIRA    
006 2018    NA                          0007-1315   Remaking The Global Economy Of Knowledge: Do New Fields Of Research Change?                     1   NA      NA      MAIA    
006 2018    NA                          0007-1315   Remaking The Global Economy Of Knowledge - Do New Fields Of Research Change.                    69  NA      NA      MAIA
```

I added the IDs manually, and they aggregate the same paper despite errors in filling the information, absense of fields, different coverage of authors, title punctuation or inclusion of subtitle, etc.

As requested on the comments, here is the same example table generated from using dput():

```
structure(list(YEAR = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), DOI = c("10.1093/brain", "10.1093/brain/awy105", 
"10.1093/brain/awy105", "10.1093/brain/awy105", "10.1093/brain/awy172", 
"10.1093/brain/awy172", "10.1093/brain/awy172", "10.1093/brain/awy172", 
"10.1093/brain/awy172", "10.1093/brain/awy172", "10.1093/brain/awy172", 
"10.1639/0007-2745-121", "10.1639/0007-2745-121", "NA", "10.1639/0007-2745-121", 
"10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547", "10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547", 
"10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.547", "10.1639/0007-2745-121.4.571", 
"NA", "NA", "NA"), ISSN = c("0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0006-8950", 
"0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0006-8950", 
"0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0006-8950", "0007-2745", "0007-2745", 
"0007-2745", "0007-2745", "0007-2745", "0007-2745", "0007-2745", 
"0007-2745", "0007-2745", "0007-1315", "0007-1315"), Title = c("JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis", 
"JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis", 
"JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis", 
"JAK inhibitor improves type I interferon induced damage: proof of concept in dermatomyositis", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"Novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"A novel complex neurological phenotype due to a homozygous mutation in FDX2", 
"The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Brazilian Atlantic Forest", 
"The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Brazilian Atlantic Forest.", 
"The latitudinal diversity gradient of epiphytic lichens in the Br. Atlantic Forest", 
"Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes: Forest in southern Brazil", 
"Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes", 
"Floristic composition, and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes", 
"Floristic composition and vertical zonation of epiphytic bryophytes", 
"Bryophytes of Jau National Park (Amazonas, Brazil): Estimating species detectability", 
"Bryophytes of Jau National Park (Amazonas, Brazil)", "Remaking The Global Economy Of Knowledge: Do New Fields Of Research Change?", 
"Remaking The Global Economy Of Knowledge - Do New Fields Of Research Change."
), Volume = c("141", "141", "141", "141", "/A", "XX", "X", "1", 
"13", "13", "141", "121", "121", "121", "21", "121", "121", "121", 
"121", "121", "1", "69"), BeginPg = c("1609", "1609", "1609", 
"1609", "NA", "NA", NA, "NA", "3096", "AWY172", "2289", "480", 
"480", "480", "547", "547", "547", "547", "571", "571", "NA", 
"NA"), EndPg = c("1621", "NA", "NA", "NA", NA, NA, "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "2298", "497", "497", "497", "553", "553", "553", 
"553", "588", "588", "NA", "NA"), Authors = c("ALVES", "ALVES | CALVET | TOQUET | AMELIN | DEPP | RODERO | HATHAZI | DUFFY | LANDON-CARDINAL", 
"ALVES | CALVET | TOQUET | LANDON-CARDINAL | AMELIN | DEPP | RODERO | HATHAZI | DUFFY", 
"BENJAMIM", "LUCATO | FREUA | CABRAL", "GIANNETTI | PAIVA | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO | THOMSEN | BASU | FREUA | LYNCH", 
"PAIVA | LUCATO | FREUA | GURGEL-GIANNETTI | LYNCH | YAMAMOTO | THOMSEN | BASU | GIAN", 
"YAMAMOTO | JULIANA GURGEL-GIANNETTI | DAVID S LYNCH | ANDERSON RODRIGUES BRANDÃO DE", 
"GIANNETTI", "GIANNETTI | LYNCH DS | PAIVA ARB | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO G | THOMSEN C | BRASU S | FREUA", 
"GIANNETTI | PAIVA | LUCATO | YAMAMOTO | FREUA | LYNCH | THOMSEN | BASU", 
"MENEZES | CACERES | BASTOS | LÜCKING", "MENEZES | CACERES | LÜCKING | BASTOS", 
"MENEZES | CACERES | BASTOS | LÜCKING", "SANTOS | OLIVEIRA", 
"OLIVEIRA | PERALTA | SANTOS", "SANTOS | OLIVEIRA | PERALTA", 
"SANTOS | PERALTA | DE OLIVEIRA", "PINILLA | GRADSTEIN | M.R. PEREIRA | BASTOS | ZARTMAN | VANDERPOORTEN", 
"PINILLA | VANDERPOORTEN | GRADSTEIN | BASTOS | ZARTMAN | PEREIRA", 
"MAIA", "MAIA")), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The best way I could think to find the matches automatically would be through a self-join, where I would 1. compare fields for all publications in each journal; 2. score and add the results to a total score per match; 3. and then empirically establish the minimum score to consider a match. The problem is that it would be quite intense to do that for 1.3 million records.

Would there be a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Hi @RuiBarradas. I have included the output of the sample table, as requested. Thanks so much for your help. Best.

Comment: As a id code, why not start with the [SOUNDEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm: `sndx <- phonics::soundex(df1$Title, clean = FALSE)`

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the approach seems to be quite interesting as a first step, but I notice soundex seems to put a lot of weight in the beginning of the title, so it generates different codes very similar titles (for example: "a novel complex..." and "novel complex..." would be different), but other titles that are similar, starting with the same structures, seem to generate the same code. This second problem I believe might be fixed using the optio "maxCodeLen", increasing the code to a size that reduces false positives. Would you know how to solve the false negatives? Thanks again.

Comment: Eyeballing the sample data, it seems like `ISSN` is a clean way to start. Have you seen any examples of different `ISSN` being the same paper, or is it ever missing?

Comment: ISSN and year are two fields I have clear extensively and the are the starting groups to a matching. The problem is that I still have many publications per ISSN and year, sometimes thousands.  That’s why a multi-column approach is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be something that studied by [Record Linkage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_linkage) literature. A `R` package to use might be `fastlink` [here](https://github.com/kosukeimai/fastLink).

In general, Record Linkage tries to solve the problem that there are two datasets: `A` and `B`, where you know that some of the `A` records must be matched with entries from `B`, but there isn't a perfect identifier to tell you so. Hence we need to leverage different columns of information to help us determine what is a match or not.

I notice that some comments suggesting `soundex` or `ISSN`, which are very useful observations, but Record Linkage methodology leverages all those information (and even more) to make the match. I believe this is something you are after.

**PS**: `doi` should be unique identifier for journal articles and `ISSN` should be identifier for journals. But some journals have both `print` and `online` ISSN, so there may be cases where two articles come from the same journal but have different `ISSN`s.

**PS2**: What would make the comparison more effective is what they called "blocking". If you take articles from same journal and same publication year, and consider them as smaller groups, then you compare articles within each group. Here you are saving lots of time and resources since you are not matching between articles that are obvious not-matches.

Comment: Great suggestion! I will experiment with fastlink to see what it can do with my dataset. For the ISSN matter, I have used several databases to consolidate all possible ISSNs per journal, and then used the ISSN-L, the common core ISSN to represent each journal. Year has also been consolidated and so I can indeed compare only within ISSN/year blocks. Let’s see how fastlink performs in that sense. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. If you think my answer is helpful, you could select it as the solution to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Once again, thank you for your solution. I spent the last few days trying to make it work, as fastLink does not seem to handle large datasets very well. Even though they include a grouping command, it could not deal with 30,000 x 6 groups (number of journals vs years covered). After several diferent attempts and a whole day running the script suppervised in slices small enough for the package to deal with and large enough so it would not produce errors (seems to happen in small datasets), it produced a nearly perfect result. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! There are many other considerations when it comes to **very** large datasets, e.g. memory issue, etc and I am happy that you solved your problem eventually.